# Inject TraceId in spring sleuth from Kafka message

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, trace, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am working on multiple microservice architecture ,where entry point is from Kafka.
eg., lets suppose we have three microservice micro1,micro2 and micro3 request in micro1 comes from kafka message queue,and it further communicate with micro2 and micro3 via Rest client.

Message which is recieved by micro1 contains requestId , which I need to put in place of TraceId in spring sleuth and that should be propogated across all microservice.

I have tried this by MDC but in that case traceId is not propogating to other microservices.

Is there any other way to implement custom TraceId in sleuth instead of Auto generated?

thanks!!

Comment: maybe you want to look at this? https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/single/spring-cloud-sleuth.html#_propagating_extra_fields

Comment: @sfat- Yes, I have tried this but in that case I have to make code changes in all the microservices to access ExtraFieldPropagation , Is there any way so that I can only modify **X-B3-TraceId** in micro1 and same will be propogated in all microservices without any code changes in other microservices.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea. Leave the generated trace id and create another generated field that will be propagated as baggage.

If you really need to change the way the ID is generated then you have to change this bean

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/v2.0.2.RELEASE/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/TraceAutoConfiguration.java#L113-L133

```
@Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    Propagation.Factory sleuthPropagation(SleuthProperties sleuthProperties) {
        if (sleuthProperties.getBaggageKeys().isEmpty() && sleuthProperties.getPropagationKeys().isEmpty()) {
            return B3Propagation.FACTORY;
        }
        ExtraFieldPropagation.FactoryBuilder factoryBuilder = ExtraFieldPropagation
                .newFactoryBuilder(B3Propagation.FACTORY);
        if (!sleuthProperties.getBaggageKeys().isEmpty()) {
            factoryBuilder = factoryBuilder
                    // for HTTP
                    .addPrefixedFields("baggage-", sleuthProperties.getBaggageKeys())
                    // for messaging
                    .addPrefixedFields("baggage_", sleuthProperties.getBaggageKeys());
        }
        if (!sleuthProperties.getPropagationKeys().isEmpty()) {
            for (String key : sleuthProperties.getPropagationKeys()) {
                factoryBuilder = factoryBuilder.addField(key);
            }
        }
        return factoryBuilder.build();
    }
```

Comment: could you give an example how could we modify this bean , also this bean is not created when spring boot is starting up and how can we access kafka message body in this bean.

Comment: Create your own bean of the same type. This bean is created during spring boot setup. The kafka message is abstracted in the Propagation.Factory. Just check out how it's done in the B3Propagation class and do exactly the same with different header names